# Karatsuba's algorithm: split the digit sequences about the middle

Tags: python, algorithm

Here is a pseudocode of karatsuba's algorithm:

```
procedure karatsuba(num1, num2)
    if (num1 < 10) or (num2 < 10)
        return num1*num2

    /* calculates the size of the numbers */
    m = max(size_base10(num1), size_base10(num2))
    m2 = m/2

    /* split the digit sequences about the middle */
    high1, low1 = split_at(num1, m2)
    high2, low2 = split_at(num2, m2)

    /* 3 calls made to numbers approximately half the size */
    z0 = karatsuba(low1, low2)
    z1 = karatsuba((low1+high1), (low2+high2))
    z2 = karatsuba(high1, high2)

    return (z2*10^(2*m2)) + ((z1-z2-z0)*10^(m2)) + (z0)
```

I didn't understand the step "split the digit sequences about the middle" especially after looking at the python implementation of 
[Karatsuba's algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42324419/karatsuba-multiplication-implementation)

Can you explain me, how exactly should we split digit sequence?

Comment: I don't understand where you're stuck.  On each iteration, you break the numbers in the middle by textual length, base 10.  For instance, the six-digit number `123456` becomes `123` and `456`.

Comment: @Prune for example the first number is 12345678 and the second is 100. Then m2 = 4. According to the code we have to split two numbers at the 4-th digit. But in the comment it's mentioned, that we should split numbers in the middle. Which statement is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On each iteration, you break the numbers in the middle by textual length, base 10. For instance, the six-digit number `123456` becomes `123` and `456`.

For the case of numbers of different lengths, note that the implementation works with the max of the two.  Given `12345678` and `100`, this effective pads the shorter number with zeros, to `00000100`.  Split into two 4-digit numbers each and continue.

Note that as an algorithm, this represents the simple binomial expansion:

```
(a + b) * (c + d) = ac + ad + bc + bd
```

In the 8-digit case, our numbers are

```
(1234*10^4 + 5678) * (0000*10^4 + 0100)
```

Does that help your understanding?

Answer (score 0):

I have written a very simple code for Karatsuba algorithm you can try this as well...

```
import timeit
import math
#loading math and time module

start_time = timeit.default_timer()
# creating a start time count down initilise to 0

def karatsuba_multiplication(nu1,nu2):          #defining a function
    num1 = str(nu1)                             #converting inteager into string because object of type inteager has no lenght
     num2 = str(nu2)
     x = len(num1)
     y = len(num2)

    if x == 1 or y == 1:
        print('----result----',nu1*nu2)
    else:
        if x >= y:
            n = x
        else:
            n = y
        if n % 2 == 0:
            n  = n
        else:
            n = n + 1
        a = int(num1[0:math.floor(x/2)])        #slicing the numbers for ltiplication
        b = int(num1[math.ceil(x/2):x])
        c = int(num2[0:math.floor(y/2)])
        d = int(num2[math.ceil(y/2):y])
        print('----reslut----',int((10**n)*(a*c) + (10**(n/2))*(a*d + b*c) + b*d))  
#formula of karatsuba

karatsuba_multiplication(9,1234)
karatsuba_multiplication(7,12345)
karatsuba_multiplication(213,1234)
karatsuba_multiplication(1234,5678)
karatsuba_multiplication(12345,987)
karatsuba_multiplication(314159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097494  
4592,2718281828459045235360287471352662497757247093699959574966967627)

stop = timeit.default_timer()                   #countdown ends here
print('program time--',stop)
```

may be this code is lenghty but it is simple.