# Similar algorithm implementation producing different results

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, karatsuba

I'm trying to understand the Karatsuba multiplication algorithm. I've written the following code:

```
def karatsuba_multiply(x, y):
    # split x and y
    len_x = len(str(x))
    len_y = len(str(y))
    if len_x == 1 or len_y == 1:
        return x*y

    n = max(len_x, len_y)
    n_half = 10**(n // 2)
    a = x // n_half
    b = x % n_half
    c = y // n_half
    d = y % n_half

    ac = karatsuba_multiply(a, c)
    bd = karatsuba_multiply(b, d)
    ad_plus_bc = karatsuba_multiply((a+b), (c+d)) - ac - bd

    return (10**n * ac) + (n_half * ad_plus_bc) + bd
```

This test case does not work:

```
print(karatsuba_multiply(1234, 5678)) ## returns 11686652, should be 7006652‬
```

But if I use the following code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42324419/karatsuba-multiplication-implementation), the test case produces the correct answer:

```
def karat(x,y):
    if len(str(x)) == 1 or len(str(y)) == 1:
        return x*y
    else:
        m = max(len(str(x)),len(str(y)))
        m2 = m // 2

        a = x // 10**(m2)
        b = x % 10**(m2)
        c = y // 10**(m2)
        d = y % 10**(m2)

        z0 = karat(b,d)
        z1 = karat((a+b),(c+d))
        z2 = karat(a,c)

        return (z2 * 10**(2*m2)) + ((z1 - z2 - z0) * 10**(m2)) + (z0)
```

Both functions look like they're doing the same thing. Why doesn't mine work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that in with `kerat_multiply` implementation you can't use the correct formula for the last return.

In the original `kerat` implementation the value `m2 = m // 2` is multiplied by 2 in the last return `(z2 * 10**(2*m2)) + ((z1 - z2 - z0) * 10**(m2)) + (z0)` **(2*m2)**

So you i think you need either to add a new variable as below where `n2 == n // 2` so that you can multiply it by 2 in the last return, or use the original implementation.

Hoping it helps :)

**EDIT**: This is explain by the fact that `2 * n // 2` is different from `2 * (n // 2)`

```
n = max(len_x, len_y)
n_half = 10**(n // 2)
n2 = n // 2
a = x // n_half
b = x % n_half
c = y // n_half
d = y % n_half

ac = karatsuba_multiply(a, c)
bd = karatsuba_multiply(b, d)
ad_plus_bc = karatsuba_multiply((a + b), (c + d)) - ac - bd

return (10**(2 * n2) * ac) + (n_half * (ad_plus_bc)) + bd
```

Comment: So, `2 * n // 2` isn't the same as `n`?

Comment: But they are not doing the same `2 * n // 2` is different from `2 * (n // 2)` here the order is important

For instance `2 * 1 // 2 = 1`  but `2 * (1 // 2) = 0`

Comment: Tested this, realized the problem is that `n` is not the same as using `n // 2 * 2` because `//` is a flooring operation. If `n` is 3, `n // 2 * 2` is 2, so it has to be floored first.

Comment: Nice :) hope it helped